# Executing JavaScript on multiple document jQuery Mobile site

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a site which I load all the content through getJSON. To keep the size of the DOM low and keep the document readable, content is loaded from separate HTML documents. The problem is when the page is loaded using AJAX no JavaScript is executed when the new page loads. If I visit the page directly, the JavaScript is executed.

Is there any way to execute some JavaScript when navigating to a new page using AJAX and when loading the page directly?

I've noticed that loading a page directly using "index.html#page2" doesn't work if they are dynamically created. It only loads the first page.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery mobile's standard behaviour is to load content from subsequestion pages with AJAX, loading only the body part of the document. Consequences are that :

- the content of the header is not loaded: any specific script of stylesheet linked only in the subsequent page is ignored
- there is no `$(document).ready()` event on loading of the page.

The proper way to do things is to

1. ensure the header of your first page links to all the scripts and stylesheets you will need
2. bind your javascript to `$(document).bind('pageinit')` intead of `$(document).ready()`

You can find more informations [there](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)